# How to perform distributed computations with F# (.Net)

Tags: .net, f#

So I just had a little fun in F# with the Async library recently and was very amazed by especially Async.Parallel which basically takes a sequence of Async tasks and unifies them under one Async task.

However, now I am curious on how to distribute a computation task between multiple computers, say for example the two laptops on my desk.

Is it somehow possible to serialize these Async tasks and send them to another computer which then performs the task and sends the result back?

Or maybe I need to serialize the data itself and send it to the other computer, on which I have some code running that performs the computation and sends result back?

Or maybe there is another simplistic way to do it?

**What is the general approach to distributed computing in F# using .Net? (recommended design patterns, tools, libraries, etc.)**

My end goal is to split a big computation task into smaller parts and run them on multiple machines. Preferably in a simplistic non-enterprise-overly-complex-way.

Comment: There is no "easy" way to do distributed computation today, regardless of the language and platform, because tools and standards are not yet quite there. I would recommend that you check out Akka.Net for a start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a project called [MBrace](http://www.mbrace.io) which does pretty much exactly what you describe :-).

It lets you write cloud computations using the `cloud` block:

```
let first = cloud { return 15 }
let second = cloud { return 27 }
```

You can compose them using `let!` as with asynchronous workflows and you can also create them from asynchronous workflows using `Cloud.ofAsync`. Cloud computations can be distributed over network using `Cloud.Parallel`:

```
cloud {
  let! results = [ first; second ] |> Cloud.Parallel
  return List.sum results }
```

Currently, there are MBrace bindings for running the computation locally (for testing) and inside Azure cluster, but there is some work-in-progress on supporting Amazon too.

For more information see [mbrace.io](http://www.mbrace.io) and there is also a nice talk from Mathias Brandewinder on [crunching through big data with MBrace](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/FSharp-Events/fsharp-ML-MVP-Summit-2015)

Comment: But this is for cloud only, and the OP asked about two computers on a desk.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I have never used MBrace but a quick look turned up [Using MBrace with a Locally Simulated Cluster](http://mbrace.io/thespian-tutorial.html). Me thinks Tomas is right.

Comment: MBrace looks very interesting indeed. 
The tutorial website says `"You can create a multi-machine cluster using instances .... this is not covered in this tutorial."`, any pointers on how to get started with making a local cluster of for example two local computers? *(I looked briefly at the mbrace documentation and didn't see any immediate obvious way to do it. Think I will have a better look at it in the coming weekend)*

Answer (score 2):

fsharp.org has a page dealing with [Cloud Data, Compute and Messaging with F#](http://fsharp.org/guides/cloud/), it provides up-to-date ressources on the matter.

As Tomas Petricek said, [MBrace](http://www.mbrace.io/) seems to be the idiomatic way to do distributed computation in F#. Sadly it focuses on cloud computing (Azure and Amazon) and provides very little information on local multi-machine clusters. I found a [thread](https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.Core/issues/165) that deals with the subject and appears to provide a solution but an official tutorial (and maybe some build-in functions) would be nice.

Microsoft's [Prajna](https://github.com/MSRCCS/Prajna/wiki/F%23-Examples) was developed in F# and offers an alternative to Sparks. The documentation explains how to build local [multi-machine clusters](https://github.com/MSRCCS/Prajna/wiki/Deploy-Prajna) (windows machine only it seems). It might be the easiest solution but it seems to be dead.

Another option might be akka.net which has an [F# API](http://getakka.net/docs/FSharp%20API).

Answer (score 2):

I definitely recommend you  akka.net. I'm currently implementing distributed integration solutions using it and can tell you this is awesome. Project Orleans by Microsoft Research is also pretty good, although it's not idiomatic f# approach